# Get actual delegates

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have the following script and I am trying to get a list of the actual delegates and remove the servers, etc

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity technology.servicespmo | where      {($_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")-or ($_.user.tostring() -ne "server\AdmEnterprise Servers Advance")-or ($_.user.tostring() -ne "server\Domain Admins")-or ($_.user.tostring() -ne "server\Exchange Domain Servers") -or ($_.user.tostring() -ne "server\Exchange Services") -or ($_.user.tostring() -ne "server\ExchangeAdmin") -or ($_.user.tostring() -ne "server\ExchangeFull") -or ($_.user.tostring() -ne "server\ExchangeView")| Select Identity,User,@{Name='Access Rights';Expression={[string]::join(', ', $_.AccessRights)}} | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation :\temp\permissions2.csv
```

It works if I have only a few entries but I want to run it against 38 different entires.

Is there an easier way,like putting the entries into an array?

Basically when I get a list of the mailbox pwermissions I am trying to remove a list of the servers and service accounts so I only get the actual users and delegates

TIA

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, something like this should work:

```
$Excluded = @(
"NT AUTHORITY\SELF",
"server\AdmEnterprise Servers Advance",
"server\Domain Admins",
"server\Exchange Domain Servers",
"server\Exchange Services",
"server\ExchangeAdmin",
"server\ExchangeFull",
"server\ExchangeView"
)


Get-MailboxPermission -Identity technology.servicespmo |
 where  { $Excluded -notcontains $_.user.tostring() } |
 Select Identity,User,@{Name='Access Rights';Expression={[string]::join(', ', $_.AccessRights)}} |
 Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation :\temp\permissions2.csv
```